# Spring batch JMS writer/reader example

Tags: jms, spring-batch, spring-jms

Anybody know of a good resource for a detailed (more so than the Spring Batch docs) look at the uses of JMS Item Writer/Reader in Spring Batch?

Specifically, and because I'm being tasked with trying to reuse an existing system whose only interface is asynchronous over a queue, I'm wondering if the following is possible:

Step 1: read some data and build a message. 
Step 2: Drop message on queue using JMSItemWriter. 
Step 3: Wait for message to come back using JMSItemReader on the response queue.
Step 4: Do some other stuff 
...
Rinse and repeat, a few thousand times a day.

Or in other words, essentially using Spring Batch to force synchronous interaction with an asynchronous resource.  I'd like to make sure before I get further in research, that this is A) possible, and B) not shameless abuse of the framework that will cause major headaches down the road.

Thanks in advance for any info.

Comment: We have done it 5 years ago. I will take a look back if I can build an example for it.